# Getting value from html with BS4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have to get value inside the red box. I tried this codes but every time I try something new it gives me irrelevant answers or exceptions. Website is using js to loaded content. When I tried to inspect f12 I can see html but I can't **scrape** content with this codes.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import bs4


chromedriver = 'D:\webdriverchrome\chromedriver.exe'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver,                 
chrome_options=options)
browser.get('website')
time.sleep(4)
girisyap = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sign-in-link"]')
time.sleep(3)
girisyap.click()
time.sleep(2)
username = browser.find_element_by_name("loginUsername")
password = browser.find_element_by_name("loginPassword")
username.send_keys("id")
time.sleep(1)
password.send_keys("password")
time.sleep(1)
girrisyap = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*        
[@id="login"]/div/div/form/div/div/button')
girrisyap.click()
time.sleep(3)
browser.get('logginedwebsite')
time.sleep(15)
innerHTML = browser.execute_script("return document.body.outerHTML")
# html = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('html').get_attribute('innerHTML')
root = bs4.BeautifulSoup(innerHTML, "lxml")
#print(root)
viewcount = root.find_all("span", attrs={'class':'value--2NhHD'})


for span in viewcount:
    print(span.string)

    driver.quit()
```

this is what output is

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

If I print root I can see bunch of html codes but there is nothing with my values

[Image of codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8pSs.jpg)

[image]

This html codes are some of html codes, when I use inspect mode on loggined website, inside html and body tag. I want the 26 value from whole html codes. Also these values are changing every 30 sec or 1 min. So after a while, "26" is becoming the second value.

```
<div class="numbers--3CyTT recent-number--2rGeB fadeable--1SHS1 all-numbers--1Jc4s">
<div class="number-container--1mKjk recent-number--2E5Lw" data-role="recent-number">
<div data-role="number-26" class="single-number--2nKGX black--2ZXP1 align-middle--30M6J first--2gxHs animate--f-O-R">
***<span class="value--2NhHD">26</span>*** #Need that line
</div></div><div class="number-container--1mKjk recent-number--2E5Lw" data-role="recent-number">
<div class="number-container--1mKjk recent-number--2E5Lw" data-role="recent-number"><div data-role="number-1" class="single-number--2nKGX red--3noFd align-middle--30M6J first--2gxHs animate--f-O-R"><span class="value--2NhHD">1</span></div></div>
```

Comment: Don't post code as images - it makes it an order of magnitude more difficult for the Stack Overflow community to debug your issue. Instead, paste the relevant parts of your code into the body of your question, as you've done with your Python snippet. See also: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: what about the second `value--2NhHD` class do you need that?

Comment: Nope I just need the first integer value. There are more same class different values

Comment: Can you print `browser.page_source` after `browser.get('website')  time.sleep(4)`? and see if the value is there

Comment: I changed the code slightly different now I can see html codes but none of them are the ones I want it. I guess js making it harder to get it.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the value of that particular span tag, instead of working with a list you can use `soup.find()`.

In this case it would be:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
volume = soup.findAll("span", class="value--2NhHD")
value = volume.text
```

Answer (score 0):

*try the following*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="numbers--3CyTT recent-number--2rGeB fadeable--1SHS1 all-numbers--1Jc4s">
<div class="number-container--1mKjk recent-number--2E5Lw" data-role="recent-number">
<div data-role="number-26" class="single-number--2nKGX black--2ZXP1 align-middle--30M6J first--2gxHs animate--f-O-R">
<span class="value--2NhHD">26</span>
</div></div><div class="number-container--1mKjk recent-number--2E5Lw" data-role="recent-number">
<div class="number-container--1mKjk recent-number--2E5Lw" data-role="recent-number">
<div data-role="number-1" class="single-number--2nKGX red--3noFd align-middle--30M6J first--2gxHs animate--f-O-R">
<span class="value--2NhHD">1</span></div></div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
element = soup.select('span.value--2NhHD')[0]
print(element.text)
```

*Prints out*

> ```
> 26
> ```

---

*Or to get all, run loop*

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
element = soup.select('span.value--2NhHD')

for span in element:
    print(span.text)
```

Comment: I guess I couldn't clarify my case. As I recently noticed the website I have to scrap is using javascript to bind html codes. When I inspect it, it gives me directly html source but my codes gives me "None" or errors of attribute.

Comment: Can you post the link

Comment: I am using Selenium to get login. So It wouldn't work if I gave you the url. I used soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source,features="html.parse") show = soup.find_all("div") to show all the div but It doesn't give the div tags in the image. It gives something else. I also used span tag too. Same irrelevant span tags it gave me.

Comment: I am gonna edit my codes in the question with selenium and I used your code. Here is the output